# How to disable UISlider?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I've seen answers about this but no actual code explaining how to, I'm new to swift so really confused on how to perform this simple task.

I have a `UISlider` However I want to disable the sliders function when an `if` statement is true.

I current have a UISlider with an `if` statement but can't workout how to disable it.

```
@IBAction func radiusSlider(sender: UISlider) {
    if location == false {
        //Disable Slider
    } else {
        radiusData.radiusValue = Double(sender.value)
        radiusLabel.text = "Radius: \(sender.value)km"
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(radiusValue, object: self)
    }
}
```

Or would this be in within the viewDidLoad? If so how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the UISlider's `enabled` property to false.

```
@IBAction func radiusSlider(sender: UISlider) {
    if location == false {
        sender.enabled = false
    } else {
        radiusData.radiusValue = Double(sender.value)
        radiusLabel.text = "Radius: \(sender.value)km"
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(radiusValue, object: self)
    }
}
```

If you want to enable/disable your slider in other functions of your view controller, you will need to make an `IBOutlet` property for your slider.

Comment: Ok I feel stupid for not using sender. I kept trying to uses radiusSlider. haha

Comment: Thank YOU!! Been confused for way to long